# A series specifying factorial

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

Is there any mathematical contraction of the following factorial series function?

$$ F(n) = 1.1! + 2.2! + 3.3! + ...... + n.n! $$

I tried it by inspecting that $$ x.x! = x^2.(x-1)!$$

I need derivation of the series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n kk!=\sum_{k=1}^n ((k+1)!-k!)=(n+1)!-1$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Notice that $$n.n!=(n+1)!-n!$$